# Julia Agents.jl: fail to precomplieAgents

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia, agents.jl

Here is what it returned to me when I run

```
using Agents
```

```
[ Info: Precompiling Agents [46ada45e-f475-11e8-01d0-f70cc89e6671]
WARNING: method definition for #GridSpace#48 at C:\Users\PC\.julia\packages\Agents\h9Ls1\src\spaces\grid.jl:46 declares type variable W but does not use it.
ERROR: LoadError: type DataType has no field size
Stacktrace:
 [1] getproperty(x::Type, f::Symbol)
   @ Base .\Base.jl:32
 [2] top-level scope
   @ C:\Users\PC\.julia\packages\JLD2\qncOK\src\data\number_types.jl:14
 [3] include(mod::Module, _path::String)
   @ Base .\Base.jl:457
 [4] include(x::String)
   @ JLD2 C:\Users\PC\.julia\packages\JLD2\qncOK\src\JLD2.jl:1
 [5] top-level scope
   @ C:\Users\PC\.julia\packages\JLD2\qncOK\src\JLD2.jl:453
 [6] include
   @ .\Base.jl:457 [inlined]
 [7] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt128}}, source::String)
   @ Base .\loading.jl:2049
 [8] top-level scope
   @ stdin:3
in expression starting at C:\Users\PC\.julia\packages\JLD2\qncOK\src\data\number_types.jl:13
in expression starting at C:\Users\PC\.julia\packages\JLD2\qncOK\src\JLD2.jl:1
in expression starting at stdin:3
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile JLD2 [033835bb-8acc-5ee8-8aae-3f567f8a3819] to "C:\\Users\\PC\\.julia\\compiled\\v1.9\\JLD2\\jl_B21B.tmp".
Stacktrace:
  [1] error(s::String)
    @ Base .\error.jl:35
  [2] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String, internal_stderr::IO, internal_stdout::IO, keep_loaded_modules::Bool)
    @ Base .\loading.jl:2300
  [3] compilecache
    @ .\loading.jl:2167 [inlined]
  [4] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId, env::String)
    @ Base .\loading.jl:1805
  [5] _require_prelocked(uuidkey::Base.PkgId, env::String)
    @ Base .\loading.jl:1660
  [6] macro expansion
    @ .\loading.jl:1648 [inlined]
  [7] macro expansion
    @ .\lock.jl:267 [inlined]
  [8] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
    @ Base .\loading.jl:1611
  [9] include(mod::Module, _path::String)
    @ Base .\Base.jl:457
 [10] include(x::String)
    @ Agents.AgentsIO C:\Users\PC\.julia\packages\Agents\h9Ls1\src\submodules\io\AgentsIO.jl:9
 [11] top-level scope
    @ C:\Users\PC\.julia\packages\Agents\h9Ls1\src\submodules\io\AgentsIO.jl:13
 [12] include(mod::Module, _path::String)
    @ Base .\Base.jl:457
 [13] include(x::String)
    @ Agents C:\Users\PC\.julia\packages\Agents\h9Ls1\src\Agents.jl:1
 [14] top-level scope
    @ C:\Users\PC\.julia\packages\Agents\h9Ls1\src\Agents.jl:38
 [15] include
    @ .\Base.jl:457 [inlined]
 [16] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt128}}, source::String)
    @ Base .\loading.jl:2049
 [17] top-level scope
    @ stdin:3
in expression starting at C:\Users\PC\.julia\packages\Agents\h9Ls1\src\submodules\io\jld2_integration.jl:2
in expression starting at C:\Users\PC\.julia\packages\Agents\h9Ls1\src\submodules\io\AgentsIO.jl:3
in expression starting at C:\Users\PC\.julia\packages\Agents\h9Ls1\src\Agents.jl:1
in expression starting at stdin:3
ERROR: Failed to precompile Agents [46ada45e-f475-11e8-01d0-f70cc89e6671] to "C:\\Users\\PC\\.julia\\compiled\\v1.9\\Agents\\jl_A1CF.tmp".
Stacktrace:
  [1] error(s::String)
    @ Base .\error.jl:35
  [2] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String, internal_stderr::IO, internal_stdout::IO, keep_loaded_modules::Bool)
    @ Base .\loading.jl:2300
  [3] compilecache
    @ .\loading.jl:2167 [inlined]
  [4] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId, env::String)
    @ Base .\loading.jl:1805
  [5] _require_prelocked(uuidkey::Base.PkgId, env::String)
    @ Base .\loading.jl:1660
  [6] macro expansion
    @ .\loading.jl:1648 [inlined]
  [7] macro expansion
    @ .\lock.jl:267 [inlined]
  [8] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
    @ Base .\loading.jl:1611
  [9] eval
    @ .\boot.jl:370 [inlined]
 [10] include_string(mapexpr::typeof(REPL.softscope), mod::Module, code::String, filename::String)
    @ Base .\loading.jl:1903
 [11] invokelatest(::Any, ::Any, ::Vararg{Any}; kwargs::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
    @ Base .\essentials.jl:819
 [12] invokelatest(::Any, ::Any, ::Vararg{Any})
    @ Base .\essentials.jl:816
 [13] inlineeval(m::Module, code::String, code_line::Int64, code_column::Int64, file::String; softscope::Bool)
    @ VSCodeServer c:\Users\PC\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.51.2\scripts\packages\VSCodeServer\src\eval.jl:261
 [14] (::VSCodeServer.var"#67#72"{Bool, Bool, Bool, Module, String, Int64, Int64, String, VSCodeServer.ReplRunCodeRequestParams})()
    @ VSCodeServer c:\Users\PC\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.51.2\scripts\packages\VSCodeServer\src\eval.jl:181
 [15] withpath(f::VSCodeServer.var"#67#72"{Bool, Bool, Bool, Module, String, Int64, Int64, String, VSCodeServer.ReplRunCodeRequestParams}, path::String)
    @ VSCodeServer c:\Users\PC\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.51.2\scripts\packages\VSCodeServer\src\repl.jl:274
 [16] (::VSCodeServer.var"#66#71"{Bool, Bool, Bool, Module, String, Int64, Int64, String, VSCodeServer.ReplRunCodeRequestParams})()
    @ VSCodeServer c:\Users\PC\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.51.2\scripts\packages\VSCodeServer\src\eval.jl:179
 [17] hideprompt(f::VSCodeServer.var"#66#71"{Bool, Bool, Bool, Module, String, Int64, Int64, String, VSCodeServer.ReplRunCodeRequestParams})
    @ VSCodeServer c:\Users\PC\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.51.2\scripts\packages\VSCodeServer\src\repl.jl:38
 [18] (::VSCodeServer.var"#65#70"{Bool, Bool, Bool, Module, String, Int64, Int64, String, VSCodeServer.ReplRunCodeRequestParams})()
    @ VSCodeServer c:\Users\PC\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.51.2\scripts\packages\VSCodeServer\src\eval.jl:150
 [19] with_logstate(f::Function, logstate::Any)
    @ Base.CoreLogging .\logging.jl:514
 [20] with_logger
    @ .\logging.jl:626 [inlined]
 [21] (::VSCodeServer.var"#64#69"{VSCodeServer.ReplRunCodeRequestParams})()
    @ VSCodeServer c:\Users\PC\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.51.2\scripts\packages\VSCodeServer\src\eval.jl:253
 [22] #invokelatest#2
    @ .\essentials.jl:819 [inlined]
 [23] invokelatest(::Any)
    @ Base .\essentials.jl:816
 [24] macro expansion
    @ c:\Users\PC\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.51.2\scripts\packages\VSCodeServer\src\eval.jl:34 [inlined]
 [25] (::VSCodeServer.var"#62#63")()
    @ VSCodeServer .\task.jl:514
```

I tried to update the packages but still not working. I've also tried to reinstall Julia, and this package will wrok for only one time after the reinstallation. Then the second time I run

```
using Agents
```

It will fail again. I've been trying to fix it for so long time.

Could anyone help me with it? Thank you very much!

Comment: You could usefully report the package versions that you are using: add the output of `] status` to your question.

Comment: Agree with @daycaster that reporting the package versions would be helpful, as this sounds like a package issue.